# Laravel: Different implementations on an instance with Servcie Container

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, dependency-injection, laravel-5.7

In Laravel, how do I resolve 2 different singleton implementations of an instance using Laravel's Service Container (https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/container).

For example, the 2 implementations I have for a `Foo` class is:

```
$this->app->singleton(Foo::class, function ($app) {
    return new Foo(config('services.foo.apiKey1'));
});
```

and

```
$this->app->singleton(Foo::class, function ($app) {
    return new Foo(config('services.foo.apiKey2'));
});
```

I then have to also resolve it somehow:

```
$fooV1 = app(Foo::class); // ?
$fooV2 = app(Foo::class); // ?
```

What is the correct way of writing and resolving 2 different singleton implementations of an instance?

**Update**

One solution I tried is as follows:

```
$this->app->singleton(Foo::class, function ($app, $parameters) {
    dump('Creating...'); // For testing only to see is actually a singleton
    $apiKey = $parameters[0] ? config('services.foo.apiKey1') : config('services.foo.apiKey2');
    return new Foo($apiKey);
});
```

and then resolve like so:

```
$fooV1 = app(Foo::class, [true]);
$fooV2 = app(Foo::class, [false]);
```

The above also correctly outputs:

```
Creating...
Creating...
```

As this is 2 different singletons.

This works for the most part. However, the singleton aspect is not respected. i.e. when creating the same foo twice:

```
$aV1 = app(Foo::class, [true]);
$bV1 = app(Foo::class, [true]);
```

Outputs:

```
Creating...
Creating...
```

It should have only outputted `Created...` once in this case, as a Foo with the same set of parameters was already created, thus not being a singleton.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Binding A Singleton

```
   $this->app->singleton('foo1', function ($app) {
     return new Foo(config('services.foo.apiKey1'));
   });

    $this->app->singleton('foo2', function ($app) {
        return new Foo(config('services.foo.apiKey2'));
     });
```

Instead of passing the Foo::class on the first parameter pass the name that you will be using to resolve that singleton you are creating

To resolve do the following

```
//a new instance of Foo is created 
$foo1 = $this->app->make('foo1'); 

//the same instance created before is returned
$foo2 = $this->app->make('foo2');
```

Let me know if i helped